# SSRS: Subscription column order differs from Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report, that used to have columns in the following order [A,B,C,D,Banana,E].  I was then asked to make some changes to my report, which I did so that the report columns now has an order of [A,Rocket Ship,Banana,B,C,D,E].

When I look in Visual Studio or look at the report on SSRS, I see the correct order, HOWEVER, when I let the subscription run, I see that it is still putting out reports with the wrong columns.  Has anyone else seen this phenomenon?  I've tried creating a brand new subscription, but I still get the old Column order.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the CSV report that is created isn't dependent on the report that is created with SSRS.  Essentially, it just spits out the results of the SQL query into a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the report using any caching or snapshots.

It **might** be using an old copy - though I would think it would be the same as one rendered manually from Report Server.

[image]